# Can I take screenshot of home screen programmatically ,without rooting my android device?

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of my home screen .How can I achieve this ? I am able to take screenshots of current activity but not the home screen .

My codes for  taking screenshot of current activity is

```
View v1 = linearlayout_var.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

If i want to  take the screenshot of  Home screen ,what I should use instead of linearlayout_var so that I can  reach  the root view of home screen .

In single line my question is how to get the root view of Homescreen ??

Comment: you can use adb to take screenshots, but i don't know if that fits your use cases.

Comment: have u found solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Hope it helps.